# Why always give me false in signature?

Tags: java, rsa, digital-signature, verify

I try in this code to verify my code, I have public key , my data and `signature`.I am read my signature from file and convert my string to `public key` then get my data and verify to signature.

```
 public static boolean verify () {
            String publickey = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQE";
            byte[] encKey = Base64.decodeBase64(publickey.getBytes());
            try {
                byte[] MACaddress = GetData();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                        "EndSignatuer.txt"));
                FileInputStream keyfis = new FileInputStream("EndSignatuer.txt");
                byte[] Signen = new byte[keyfis.available()];
                keyfis.read(Signen);
                keyfis.close();

                X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encKey);
                KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);

                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
                byte[] deSignen = Base64.decodeBase64(Signen);
                byte[] decrypted_digest = cipher.doFinal(deSignen);

                MessageDigest md5_digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                md5_digest.update(MACaddress);
                byte[] digest = md5_digest.digest();

                   if (decrypted_digest == digest) {
                        return true;
                    }else {
                        return false;//her why give me false 
                    }
```

Code encryption:

```
public static void GenarationKEY(byte[] data) {

        try {
            File fileEndSignatuer = new File("EndSignatuer.txt");
            FileOutputStream fopEndSignatuer = new FileOutputStream(
                    fileEndSignatuer);
            // /Read private key from file
            FileInputStream keyfis = new FileInputStream("PiveteKey.txt");
            byte[] PrivateKeyB = new byte[keyfis.available()];
            keyfis.read(PrivateKeyB);
            keyfis.close();
            byte[] decodePrivetekey = Base64.decodeBase64(PrivateKeyB);
            // /get private key
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(
                    decodePrivetekey);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PrivateKey privKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(pubKeySpec);
            // / make hash
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privKey);
            // /make encoding
            MessageDigest md5_digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            byte[] digest = md5_digest.digest(data);
            byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(digest);
            byte[] degnatureencode = Base64.encodeBase64(cipherText);
            fopEndSignatuer.write(degnatureencode);
            fopEndSignatuer.flush();
            fopEndSignatuer.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what you do is not quite RSA digital signature. Use [Signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html) class instead of combination [Cipher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) and [MessageDigest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html). Or if you insist to do it on low level, then consult [specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt), particularly section 9.2.

Secondly, string `MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQE` doesn't represent RSA public key neither it is proper Base64-encoded data.

Also you want to use [Arrays.equals(byte[], byte[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28byte%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D%29http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28byte%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D%29) instead of equality operator, as the latter just ensures that array object is the same, while the former compares actual content of the arrays.